# What is the name of this game?

Tags: game-theory

I'm hoping someone here might help me identify the name of the game below.

Is it simply a deadlock game where mutual defection is a weak nash equilibrium?

```
                  Player 2

                 C       D
              -----------------
           C  | 0, 0  |  0, 1 |
Player 1      -----------------
           D  | 1, 0  |  1, 1 |
              -----------------
```

More generally:

```
                  Player 2

                 C       D
              -----------------
           C  | a, a  |  a, b |
Player 1      -----------------
           D  | b, a  |  b, b |
              -----------------
```

Where b > a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Games](http://www.mdpi.com/journal/games) article [Names for Games: Locating 2 × 2 Games](http://www.mdpi.com/2073-4336/6/4/495/pdf) by Bryan Randolph Bruns, this game is "Double Harmony".

It's particularly boring since your "defect" just means "take the high payoff", and there's no reason for either player not to.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that the game isn't particularly interesting, but I just wanted to get a sense of what it would be called. Thanks for the answer and for the excellent link!